# Bootstrap Timepicker init time change

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, timepicker

How to dynamically change init time in Bootstrap Timepicker?

http://jdewit.github.com/bootstrap-timepicker/

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 9):

If you don't want to use the `current` time (which is the one by default), you can either use the options on initialization :

```js
$('someSelector').timepicker({defaultTime: '11:42 PM'});
```

Or you can use the value attribute of the input (which simplifies the initialization for several time pickers) :

```html
<input type="text" class="myClass input-small" value="12:42 PM">
```

```js
$('.myClass').timepicker({defaultTime: 'value'});
```

[Demo (jsfiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherbrow/qW2wL/)

Comment: I cannot use the `{defaultTime: 'value'}` feature.. Had to pick it up with `.attr('value')` :/ Any idea why? EDIT: Maybe some changes on https://github.com/tispratik/bootstrap-timepicker-rails

Comment: @carlos you are not using the same fork of the plugin. Check the link in the question.

Comment: Had the same question and can verify the {defaultTime: 'value'} works from based on the master branch  [commit](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/commit/796688ba405916186aeae4326165b219f4c6659d)

Comment: @Johnny4000 I'm sure you mean [this commit](https://github.com/jdewit/bootstrap-timepicker/commit/af8619f4ba85950940091e5c3d08d07656577b7e#L0R149)

Answer (score 3):

I'm the author the timepicker.

The 'value' option for default time has been deprecated. You have a variety of ways to set the default time to a specific value

set the value attribute

```
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <input id="timepicker" type="text" value="12:45 AM"/>
</div>
```

or set the data attribute to override the config option

```
<div class="bootstrap-timepicker">
    <input id="timepicker" type="text" data-default-value="12:45 AM"/>
</div>
```

or on init

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    defaultValue: '12:45 AM'
});
```

or call the setTime method

```
$('#timepicker').timepicker();
$('#timepicker').timepicker('setTime', '12:45');
```

Just open an issue on github if you have any problems!

Comment: this doesnt seem to work for me... http://bit.ly/YjublF  just posted to github - thanks!

Comment: You wrote this `$('#timepicker').timepicker({
    defaultValue: '12:45 AM'
});` but in your demo page you used `defaultTime` not `defaultValue`, so where it is correct? When I use `defaultTime` it doesn't work for me

Comment: @jdewit please mention tha how to hide it after selection.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is:

```
var time = '@Model.MarketTime.ToString("h:mm tt")'

        $('#timepicker-default').timepicker('setTime', time);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-append bootstrap-timepicker span8"><input id="timeinput" type="text" class="timepicker-2 input-small" value="current"><span class="add-on"><i class="icon-time"></i></span></div>
```

That works for me...